# Block quotes key for firefox in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

when i try to press quotes key (') on my webpage firefox opens default **Quick find links only**  but i don't want that to come on my webpage.

Comment: That's standard behaviour in Firefox.

Comment: but in my website i don't want to loose control off my website so is there any way to do it.

Comment: Use a different browser? What do you mean by "control of my website"

Comment: but if any other person on my webpage uses firefox then??

Comment: Use a key that is not reserved by any browser

Comment: *but in my website i don't want to loose control...* you show it to the world, so you already gave up control.

Comment: if you know how do to then only reply don't write stupid lines yoshi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try:

```
$(document).on('keydown',function(e){
    if(e.which === 52 && !$(e.target).is(':input')) e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/wST3M/ But the key code can vary from culture to culture and unfotunately onkeypress cannot be used here. So best bet would be to not do what you are trying to do. Use other shortcut than `'`